# CELLTABLE in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

How to use GWT CellTable for the following Layout

Each row has a checkBox and a Label/HTML content.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, create a class like that

```
public class MyObject{
    private CheckBox checkBox;
    private HTML html;

    public Contact(CheckBox checkBox, HTML html) {
      this.checkBox = checkBox;
      this.html = html;
    }

        // getter & setter
  }
```

after that create cell table

```
CellTable<MyObject> cellTable = new CellTable<MyObject>();
```

then create columns

```
 TextColumn<MyObject> firstColumn = new TextColumn<MyObject>() {
      @Override
      public CheckBox getValue(MyObject object) {
        return object.getCheckBox;
      }
    };
  cellTable.addColumn(firstColumn , "Checkbox");
```

and second column

```
 TextColumn<MyObject> secondColumn = new TextColumn<MyObject>() {
      @Override
      public HTML getValue(MyObject object) {
        return object.getHtml;
      }
    };
  cellTable.addColumn(secondColumn , "HTML");
```